# Trying to format date, always getting invalid date

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

The user selects a date from a jquery datepicker, it has following format:

```
DD.MM.YYYY
```

When the user submits the form, I want to transform the date input to UTC using moment. However whatever I do with the input, I get a `Invalid Date` error.

E.g. input is

```
30.03.2014
```

I try to format:

```
console.log(moment(input).format('MM/DD/YY')); <-- prints Invalid Date
```

I try to

```
console.log(moment(input).utc().toDate()); <-- prints invalid date
```

It seems that moment cannot parse the input, it can parse MM.DD.YY format, however the input must have DD.MM.YYYY format.

Any ideas whats wrong?

---

Using

```
moment(input, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

gives me:

```
{ from: '01.03.2014', to: '30.03.2014' }
{ from: Sat Mar 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
  to: Tue Apr 01 2014 11:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider using moment's hinting support:

```
moment(input, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

A Fiddle demonstrating the approach is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/x4Xm3/

Moment will assume local time inputs, so if you are working outside of that timezone you may want to append the timezone to your input. See the docs at http://momentjs.com/docs - in particular parseZone() and "String + Format" sections.

In the case of server-side (node), you are probably getting odd results because of the server's timezone.

Comment: thank you, there is still something weired, see my edit. 30.03 is converted to 01.04

Comment: I noticed, as soon as I add a day or an hour to the date, momentjs converts it to CEST, instead of using CET.

Comment: @Peter, what if you don't know the format of the hint support? Let's say a API is sending back a date, but it's format could vary? What is the best approach then? Thanks

Comment: @RichardBailey Nothing is going to be able to magically figure out all date formats for you if they are changing - for example the date 3/8/16 could be 3rd August or 8th March. You'll need to create your own code to pick the best hinting based on what you know about how the API changes dates I guess. Who would create an API where the format of the returned dates changes?!

Comment: @PeterBailey An idiot I guess - thanks for the response1